# Which perks and skills needed to get Tabula Rasa?

Tags: payday-2

I am trying to get the 'Tabula Rasa' achievement on PAYDAY 2 and I wanted to know what the required perks and skills are to get it. You can view it here: http://steamcommunity.com/stats/PAYDAY2/achievements/. I have already got the dodge build, with only a 10% chance of dodging. I do not want to spend my points on getting a 30% chance but is the 30% chance required?

Comment: You can't use skills if you want that achievement. It's all about actual skill and tactics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do the Tabula Rasa achievement you, and your entire crew, needs to have no skill points assigned at all, and wear no armour (suits only).  You also need to equip the Golden AK.762 rifle and a Chicago Typewriter submachine gun whilst in Overkill or Deathwish (a crazy thing to do IMO).  You can use any melee weapon you like, however I would recommend you try not to get into a situation where you would need any.

For your perk deck I'd probably pick Rogue (completed) as then you'll get some Dodge which helps, a little, but the higher your dodge chance the better - less damage means you'll live longer.  IIRC the dodge chance is per bullet, not that 30% of bullets will miss.  Just stay crouched, move constantly as if you stop you'll be an easy target, and take planned shots - remember you won't have much ammo.  Day 1 is the hardest due to lack of cover, but my crew and I managed to do Day 2 a lot easier (took a couple of attempts, and a few more to complete Day 1).   When you're escaping move together, as it's important you don't get downed in the final bit as you'll risk it for anybody coming to save you.

My source(s) for this are the Achievements page which tells you exactly what you need re guns / skills, and from completing it when it comes to the perk deck.

Edit: You can modify the weapons you use to whatever specification you want (assuming you have the necessary mods), this will make it a little easier rather than using the base specifications.

Comment: Also note that while you have to equip exactly these weapons, you can mod them as much as you want. You can also choose whatever melee weapon you like.

Comment: Yes indeed, I forgot about that, always handy to increase the weapons specs!  Although on a side note I did watch a video of somebody doing it solo with unmodded weapons... looked crazy.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include that information?

Comment: I've updated it now.

Comment: Does the whole crew have to have all of the same weapons and suits... Or is it just me?

Comment: All human players need to have no skills, suits, and the weapons. I specify human players because you can bring the AI and they won't interfere with getting the achievement.

Comment: @odixon I don't mean to be rude, but the description of the achievement is pretty clear there: "complete the heist on OVERKILL difficulty or above with **each crew member** using no skills, wearing suits, wielding Golden AK.762 rifles and Chicago Typewriter submachine guns"

Comment: Could I trick the game into allowing me armour by taking the armour bag and using it right away?

Comment: I've not tried it, but some people say you can.  Though any armour you have access to would be basic and just end up reducing your dodge.

Answer (score 2):

While other people say "use the Rogue perk deck, its super op and stuff", I prefer the Grinder deck.

Shoot, go to cover, regen, rinse and repeat - just shoot a bullet at an enemy and you'll get 40 health back over a 4 second time span.
It's even better when coupled with Molotovs as the fire damage will count towards your health regen (as it is damage to enemies). Molotovs can also be used to stun-lock specials, which will make killing specials a stroll in the park.

Also be sure to mod your weapons, as it can help out a lot in this attempt to get both the achievement and the extra skill set.

Good luck heisters! (or heister if you are crazy enough to attempt this solo)

Comment: This post was ages ago when Grinder was not out.

Comment: Yes, but it is still a valid answer for anyone having the same problem as OP.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the GAMBLER perk deck, at least one or two members of your group should have it. The GAMBLER perk deck revolves around ammo pick ups, when you pick up ammo from enemies- your entire team gets ammo, and some health. It's incredibly useful, and I attach it to my medic builds for the ultimate support.

Comment: This is a good answer as whenever you pick up ammo you get more health. However I cannot decide whether to use Rouge or Gambler as Rouge is focused on dodging.

Answer (score 1):

I did it first try (II-77) solo with the two bots. I had shelieghle ⬅sp and rogue perk deck, fully completed. For some reason it seemed easier than usual.. All you have to do is stay alive and take hostages for when your bots get captured.

I closed 2 doors (one was on the sniper side) The other on the main hallway. There were only 3 doors total so I lucked out. I used the two remaining cards to open the infirmary, which was well needed and the last card I did not save for the escape door; but to open the computer room where you download the keys.

I should also note that both my A.K. And typewriter were mod and helped a bit to have the laser sight and increased damage.

All in all don't panic and take your time. Kill the cloakers and leave your bots to kill the dozers. Also take out snipers as they will dowb you and your team very fast. I only had to kill 3 since I stayed in the control room 80% of the time. Good luck.

PS4 Gamer!!! Gods42Flesh0

Answer (score -1):

I did it from first attempt with 2 random allies without bot. Muscle perk deck - my favorite. Rogue - useless here, imho. Just be quick, smart and deadly.

Btw, one Gambler perk deck in team sounds good.